# How to partially validate form, only non-blank fields, even when they are required, in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

We are using some complex form workflow where we want to have a kind of Ajax prevalidation verifications all the time before final submission (and validation). So we are making an Ajax request to the server and validating the form, but not saving the results. If there are errors, we display them to the user.

But the issue is with required fields which all get marked as missing values, when they are empty (because the user has not yet finalized the form's content). So my question is, how can we make a validation run on only those fields which are not empty? For final submission we will validate all fields and catch missing fields. But for this partial validation we would like to have only filled fields validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to iterate through the form fields setting `required=False` prior to validation.  In your ajax view, something like this should work:

```
for field in myform.fields.itervalues():
    field.required = False
json_result = json.dumps({'form_valid': myform.is_valid()})
```